# Begin level: migration how can I know how many other key words exist except 'rename' and 'rename_column'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Basically my question is as the topic. My further purpose want to say how to go deeper in ROR.

I just find 'ruby on rails' document is not sufficient enough. Is there some material very comprehensively given all the command? How can I know how many other key words exist except 'rename' and 'rename_column'? How many kinds of commands exist?

```
class FixColumnNames < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :table_name do |t|
      t.rename :old_column1, :new_column1
      t.rename :old_column2, :new_column2
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This all [commands](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) you have.

Comment: These aren't key words, they are **method names**.  You can see them all in the API (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html), or list them in the console with `ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Table.methods`